# ServerManager does not commit changes to IIS (new application)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am on Win7 with vs2013 & I have installed the Microsoft.Web.Administration package into VS. From this I have a reference to the Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll and all works just fine when connecting to my IIS server and I can see all my sites.
I create a new application using this straight forward code:

```
ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager();
Microsoft.Web.Administration.Site site = iisManager.Sites["Default Web Site"];
site.Applications.Add("/Test", @"c:\blah\blah");               
iisManager.CommitChanges();
```

The Application is added because I can see that site.Applications.Count has increased but I don't see the application in the IIS console and when I re-create the ServerManager object and check Sites.Applications the application is missing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the problem - it is related to the instance of ServerManager calling CommitChanges. In my pseudo code I used

```
Microsoft.Web.Administration.Site site = iisManager.Sites["Default Web Site"];
```

but in reality I have a routine that gets the reference to the site and in that routine I was creating a new instance of ServerManager. As soon as I used the  same instance of ServerManager to get the site and to commit changes all was ok. A bit obscure...